# JHipster gateway application login failing

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

Application started. When I try to login, getting below error. Please help
I am using Jhipster v6.10.1 to generate gateway application. Application created and started without any error. But when I login getting below error

```
2020-08-25 12:00:00.048 DEBUG 24965 --- [ay-scheduling-1] c.c.m.gateway.service.AuditEventService  : Enter: removeOldAuditEvents() with argument[s] = []
Hibernate: select persistent0_.event_id as event_id1_1_, persistent0_.event_date as event_da2_1_, persistent0_.event_type as event_ty3_1_, persistent0_.principal as principa4_1_ from jhi_persistent_audit_event persistent0_ where persistent0_.event_date<?
2020-08-25 12:00:00.221  WARN 24965 --- [ay-scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2020-08-25 12:00:00.221 ERROR 24965 --- [ay-scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT" not found; SQL statement:
select persistent0_.event_id as event_id1_1_, persistent0_.event_date as event_da2_1_, persistent0_.event_type as event_ty3_1_, persistent0_.principal as principa4_1_ from jhi_persistent_audit_event persistent0_ where persistent0_.event_date<? [42102-200]
2020-08-25 12:00:00.223 ERROR 24965 --- [ay-scheduling-1] c.c.m.gateway.service.AuditEventService  : Exception in removeOldAuditEvents() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement' and exception = 'could not prepare statement; SQL [select persistent0_.event_id as event_id1_1_, persistent0_.event_date as event_da2_1_, persistent0_.event_type as event_ty3_1_, persistent0_.principal as principa4_1_ from jhi_persistent_audit_event persistent0_ where persistent0_.event_date<?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement'

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select persistent0_.event_id as event_id1_1_, persistent0_.event_date as event_da2_1_, persistent0_.event_type as event_ty3_1_, persistent0_.principal as principa4_1_ from jhi_persistent_audit_event persistent0_ where persistent0_.event_date<?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy221.findByAuditEventDateBefore(Unknown Source)
    at com.cj.microservices.gateway.service.AuditEventService.removeOldAuditEvents(AuditEventService.java:53)
    at com.cj.microservices.gateway.service.AuditEventService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d9f722d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.cj.microservices.gateway.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.cj.microservices.gateway.service.AuditEventService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d54389.removeOldAuditEvents(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2034)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT" not found; SQL statement:
select persistent0_.event_id as event_id1_1_, persistent0_.event_date as event_da2_1_, persistent0_.event_type as event_ty3_1_, persistent0_.principal as principa4_1_ from jhi_persistent_audit_event persistent0_ where persistent0_.event_date<? [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1970)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2827)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2959)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuerySub(Parser.java:2817)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:2649)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2620)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:868)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:352)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 81 common frames omitted

2020-08-25 12:00:00.225 ERROR 24965 --- [ay-scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
```

Application generated with Jhipster v6.10.1
Application type : gateway

jdl code used below

```
application {
  config {
    baseName gateway,
    packageName com.microservices.gateway,
    applicationType gateway,
    authenticationType oauth2,
    prodDatabaseType mysql,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    testFrameworks [protractor]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolve after changing hibernate ddl-auto from none to update

```
Spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

---

Another update. Issue was related Docker. I was running MySql in Docker container. It was throwing error
`mbind: Operation not permitted` .
Added

```
security_opt:    
 - seccomp:unconfined
```

to docker yaml file to resolve issue and reverted ddl-auto to none

Comment: It's a bad idea and should not be considered as a solution, JHipster never uses Hibernate-DDL to manage db schema this is delegated entirely to Liquibase. Mixing both will only cause you trouble.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you for letting me know. I am new to Liquidbase, not sure what config is missing to update database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe something went wrong earlier in the app startup phase when Liquibase creates the schema and you did not notice in the logs or maybe there's a regression in generator. The creation of this table can be found in src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml, Please check that this is the case, delete your database and restart the app and check the logs from Liquibase.

Comment: I recreated application and started. below is what I observed in logs
```
2020-08-26 20:01:52.133 DEBUG 2563 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.m.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
2020-08-26 20:01:52.276  WARN 2563 --- [ coreapp-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
,,,
My DB server is up and running. Still liquidbase did not create initial schema. Any suggestions to troubleshoot?

Comment: After troubleshooting found real issue. It was with Docker. I was running MySql in Docker container. It was throwing error `mbind: Operation not permitted` . Added `security_opt:
    - seccomp:unconfined` to docker yaml file to resolve issue.

Comment: Great! Do you think these settings would make sense for everyone and so should be integrated in the generated docker yaml file? If so, you should report it to JHipster project on github. Also could you either delete this answer or edit it to avoid mistaking others?